# What algorithm does mayavi.mlab.pipeline.iso_surface.IsoSurface use?

Tags: python, vtk, enthought, mayavi

I've been sifting through the Mayavi documentation and Google but I can't find any statement about what algorithm the IsoSurface class uses.  If it helps, my source data comes from a 3D NumPy array passed to the `mayavi.mlab.pipeline.scalar_field` function.  Here's the code for using the iso_surface function on an image containing a 3D cube:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
img = np.pad(np.ones((5,5,5)), 1, mode='constant')
src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(img, figure=False)
iso = mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(src, contours=0.5)
```

The `iso_surface` function generates an instance of IsoSurface.  The code in mayavi\modules\iso_surface.py shows that mayavi.components.contour is used.  The comments in mayavi\components\contour.py state that it wraps tvtk.ContourFilter.  From the code found at tvtk\tvtk_classes.zip\tvtk_classes\contour_filter.py in my local installation, I found this in the `__init__` method for the `ContourFilter` class:

```
tvtk_base.TVTKBase.__init__(self, vtk.vtkContourFilter, obj, update, **traits)
```

Looking at the source [code](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Filters/Core/vtkContourFilter.cxx) for `vtkContourFilter` and associated documentation on [www.vtk.org](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkContourFilter.html) I don't see a reference to a publication or the name of the algorithm implemented there.

Comment: It's open source, go look for yourself.

Comment: That doesn't help, since its documentation is pretty sparse.  I am looking for a name or reference to a publication where the algorithm was first published.  I eventually found from the source code that IsoSurface doesn't use Marching Cubes, but my original question remains unanswered.

Comment: I guess posting said code wouldn't hurt then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already discovered, Mayavi's `iso_surface` module uses (eventually) VTK's `vtkContourFilter`.  There are a couple of sentences in the book "Visualization Toolkit: An Object-Oriented Approach to 3D Graphics, 4th Edition" (Schroeder, Martin and Lorensen) that say something about the algorithms used by `vtkContourFilter`.  This is from p.198 of that book:

> Contouring in VTK is implemented using variations of the marching
>   cubes algorithm presented earlier. [...] For example, the tetrahedron
>   cell type implements "marching tetrahedron" and creates triangle
>   primitives, while the triangle cell type implements "marching
>   triangles" and generates line segments.

There's also a `vtkMarchingCubes` filter that's specific to the case of image data (regularly spaced data on a 1d, 2d or 3d grid); the book goes on to compare execution times between `vtkMarchingCubes` and `vtkContourFilter` for a 3d volume.

Comment: Is there an electronic version of this book available for free?  I have since switched to using `vtkMarchingCubes`, which generates a much simpler mesh compared to `iso_surface`.  Is that normal?

Comment: Re: electronic version.  Not that I know of, I'm afraid.  To your second question: I honestly don't know whether it's normal (I'm only a casual VTK user at best), but it sounds very plausible: my understanding is that the general algorithm triangulates everything first and then does the marching tetrahedra; I'd expect that to take longer and to give a more complex mesh.